# OpenSSL 1.0: Remove Elliptic Curves Extension

Tags: openssl, ssl

Is there any way to remove the elliptic curves extension - elliptic_curves and ec_point_formats?

(Via function like [SSL_CTX_set_options](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_options.html) with SSL_OP_NO_TICKET for the SessionTicket extension, or by conditional compilation, or something else that works...)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with conditional compilation - 
When running the Configure script, it's needed to run it with additional flags:
perl Configure VC-WIN32 no-ec [no-ecdh] [no_ecdsa]